# String is not matching using contains in Java

Tags: java, regex, contains

I'm using `list` to match string. Please take a look at my source code:

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("my-name-is-foo");

match = list.contains("(.*)name(.*)");
```

This program is giving `false` as an output.

Please help me!

Comment: I'm pretty sure "contains" here is going to look for an exact match.. not perform any regex matching. You'll need to manally loop over the contents of the list and check each string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contains()` method of class `ArrayList` does not take a regular expression, as you seem to think it does.

A line like this:

```
match = list.contains("(.*)name(.*)");
```

will look for the literal string `"(.*)name(.*)"`, and not do regular expression matching.

If you want to do regular expression matching, you'll have to loop over the strings in the list and test for each one if it matches the regular expression.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*)name(.*)");

for (String element : list) {
    if (pattern.matcher(element).matches()) {
        System.out.println("Found a match: " + element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To check  contents of list against regex, you need to iterate it:

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("my-name-is-foo");

match = false;
for (String s : list) {
    if (s.matches("(.*)name(.*)")) {
        match = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

`List#contains` checks existence by equality, not by applying regular expression on elements.

In Java 8:

```
match = list.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.matches("(.*)name(.*)"));
```

Comment: How can we print all elements which match using java 8 lambda expression?

Comment: I'll give a snippet after a minute

Comment: To print all elements that match, use: `match = list.stream().filter(s -> s.matches("(.*)name(.*)")).forEach(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 style:

```
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("1-name-1");
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)name(.*)");
    boolean f = list.stream().anyMatch(p.asPredicate());
```

Answer (score 0):

The contains method of an ArrayList does not support regular expression queries or wildcards. Check this stackoverflow post on how you can implement this:

[Search for a regexp in a java arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306880/search-for-a-regexp-in-a-java-arraylist)